# are there issues with generating a new wrapper for each test in Enzyme?

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

I'm doing tests for my React project using Jest + Enzyme.

Currently I would generate a new wrapper for each test in a suite.

example:

```
it('should render a title', () => {
 let wrapper = shallow(<Component />);
 expect(wrapper.find('#title')).toHaveLength(1);
});

it('should call closeModal function when clicked', () => {
 let wrapper = shallow(<Component />);
 wrapper.instance().closeModal = jest.fn();
 let targetFunction = wrapper.instance().closeModal;
 expect(targetFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I would like to know whether this is the standard or should I be generating the wrapper in a beforeAll and referencing that one.

I'm interested in this for the potential improvement in speed time. Right now I have 190 tests and they are done in 21.38s.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `beforeAll` is that it will use the same instance in all of your test. If you now change the internal state or props of a component in one of you test this can influent the result of the other test.

Normally I would use `beforeAll` to test different parts of a component without having a generic test like `'renders correct'` but multiple small ones like `'renders the title'`, `'renders the body'` and so on, were every test tests a single part of the component, as this will make it easier to find the place where something went wrong if the test fails.

Comment: so you're saying that you are using beforeAll when the wrapper is generated with the same properties, and when the tests are testing various parts of the same wrapper instance?
that was what I was alluding to, but I am also curious as to how much faster the testing is when doing this rather than generating a new wrapper each time.

Comment: I don't think that it will your test make much faster, cause rendering a component with shallow, should not be that slow. The only reason would be to simplify your tests. Maybe when rendering with mount the impact is a bit more significant.

Comment: fair point. if I ever decided to test it out I'll come back here and report the duration differences. thanks!